# Suggestions for an ASP.Net webforms application architecture?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I created an empty Visual Studio solution and added two projects: Backend(Class Library type) that will have the.edmx file for accessing information; and Frontend(ASP.Net type) that will have the database in the app_data folder.

Is this a good architectural design or is there a more proven way to organize this type of application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting the data access code into a library project is a good idea. I'm currently working on an ASP.NET project which is almost the same - I have a library class that I use to access the data, and in the other project I have my aspx pages. The only difference is that my data is in SQL Server (using entity framework to access that data via a .DBML file).

For the type of site you're building (data in the App_Data folder) it sounds like it will be a simple site which does not need to do anything too intense i.e. `scaling`.

Answer (score 0):

Most often it depends on the size of your project, but generally I tend to separate the front-end stuff from the backend s.t. it gets reusable. So to that direction your organization is already fine.

If you want to go a step further, I'd take a look at layered application architectures. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324603/architecture-for-winforms-applications) here may give you some insight into that and you may find some reusable elements.

Personally I don't really like the DB to reside in the "app_data" folder of the UI project (i.e. the ASP.net Web Application project). But for small apps it's fine :)