# Switching between to Forms within a single window

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change my form 1 into form 2. I don't want it to open a new window but keep it in the same window and then be able to go back and forth when I press the Next key or back key. Is the only way to do this by Individually hiding each button and picture?

Comment: I updated your tags to include Windows Forms, which is what I assume you meant.

Comment: You can put two panels to a form with DockFill Dock property, put controls on them and then switch the panels back and forth.

Comment: @Nick - while technically possible, this approach leads to a codebase which is nearly impossible to maintain. I've had to maintain forms where an entire application was developed within a tab control (MainForm with over 15,000 lines of code). It makes me feel sick every time a change request comes through for one of these applications.

Comment: You could put all your controls into a panel then just hide the panel, which will also hide all the controls in the panel. But I suspect you are trying to do something else and I suggest you read Reed's response below or CurtisHx's comment

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I couldn't agree more with you. I would at least derive a panel and put all controls on it. I thought that this is the simplest solution, certainly not the best possible one.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to consider a different approach.

You can't change one type of form into a different type of form.  The closest option would be to close or hide the first and show the second at the same location on the screen.

However, you could approach this differently.  Instead of putting your buttons and logic into a form, you could place everything into two `UserControl` instances, and just change which user control is visible within a single form.

Comment: +1 This a great approach, especially combined with [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) or some other relevant [architectural pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

You can use panels, group boxes, TabControls, etc. to group common controls together.  When you want to switch between different "screens", you can hide or show the group control by setting the `visible` property and calling `BringToFront()`, and it will hide/show all the controls on that group control.

Comment: I repeat, while technically possible, this is really, really un-recommended. Don't do this. Your fellow programmers will probably hate you if you do.

Comment: Cyborgx is correct. Its messy and unmaintainable. User controls are a better option.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324603/architecture-for-winforms-applications